# Build issues with neo4j.

Tags: java, build, neo4j

I'm trying to build `Neo4J` , I have downloaded the source from github: `neo4j-master.zip` 
containing the source,

When I build this I hit upon following errors. tried to find out in google but 
couldn't relavant details, I'm new to this product and i'm sure I have missed something 
related to `.git` can any one help me if identifing this problem .

```
Messages from Maven:

[INFO] Neo4j ............................................. SUCCESS [8.300s]
[INFO] Licensing configuration ........................... SUCCESS [3.338s]
[INFO] Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel ..................... FAILURE [2.371s]
.
.
.
.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.4:rev
ision (generate-git-hash) on project neo4j-kernel: .git directory could not be f
ound! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

I'm using mvn clean install command for initiating the build. it appears that `.git` directory is missing, i'm unable to locate if any plugins needs to be included.

Comment: Can I ask why you are building from source?

Comment: I'm trying to setup a build environment of this product, I'm trying to explore the product.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to build from source. Since you seem to use maven, you can a the following to your dependency list:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
<artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
<version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks tstorms, I could proceed further, this was because i had not cloned the code from github, after i got the code cloned I was able to proceed further.

Comment: Ok great, but why do you build the code yourself? Have you made a patch?